# Web service expects parameter to be long int but no long int support in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, long-integer

I have to call a web service, which expects it's parameter to be of type `long integer`. I do not have access to the server logs, so I don't know why am I getting an error response from server. I am trying to send a parameter as string or float, but would a server automatically cast it in such a scenario? If not, **how is it possible to call a web service needing** `long integer` **parameters with PHP**?

I was told by the administrator, that my calls contain a different session identifier (the parameter we re talking about) and that it is probably due to overflow of the integer type.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post any code examples & error messages you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting error message in that sense. The web service returns a mixed type object, which, in case of any error found, tells me tht something has gone wrong - that is, the server does respond, the web service call is successful, it's just not giving me the kind of object expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a webservice, it receives the long integer as string anyway. Just send the number and it should just work.

Comment: Thank you, I will gives this a try!

Comment: What is the protocol that you use to access the ws?

Comment: I am not sure, I am new to this web service business. I am trying to consume the web service with a SoapClient object in WSDL mode. I've tried sending the data typecasted to a string, but it didn't help, although it could be that the error is a different one this time - so hard without access to the server error logs. :/

Comment: You should use new SoapVar($your_int, XSD_LONG); Of course, $your_int can hold only 32 bit, limitation of php.

Comment: Your last suggestion did not work, although it helped me to get to the solution: I had to pass the variable with SoapVar($int_as_string,  XSD_STRING). I don't understand though, because the wsdl/xsd defined it as long (<xs:element name="transactionId" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>).